# Calculus 2: Finding Volume of object in 3D space rotating on x-axis

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I am stuck on the following problem.

> Find the volume of the solid, generated by revolving the region bounded by $y = \sqrt{\sin(4x)}, y = 0$ and $0 \le x \le \frac{\pi}{4}$ about the $x$-axis.

To solve for volume, I have the following integral
$$
V = \int_0^{\pi/4} \pi r(x)^2 dx
  = \pi \int_0^{\pi/4} \sin (4x) dx
  = \pi \left[- \frac{\cos(4x)}{4}\right]_0^{\pi/4}
  = \frac{\pi}{4}.
$$
That is not one of the solution options.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: Did you consider the fact that $cos0$ "contributes" to the answer?

Comment: oh!  dang, yes I see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
V = \pi \int_0^{\pi/4} r(x)^2 dx
  = \pi \int_0^{\pi/4} \sin(4x) dx
  = \left. -\frac{\pi}{4} \cos (4x) \right|_0^{\pi/4}
  = -\frac{\pi}{4} [-1 -1]
  = \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Comment: thank you!  where do you go to type out your math like that?

Comment: @PineNuts0 I learned LaTeX in school and here are the local [MathJaX instructions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/16192)

Answer (score 0):

If you evaluate $\pi[-1/4\cos (4x)]_0^{\pi/4}=-\pi/4(-1-1)=\pi/2$.

Comment: thank you!  where do you go to type out your math?

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/403337 .